# Invalid attempt to read when no data is present in my MVC controller

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc

When I am executing this, I am getting the following error:

> "Invalid attempt to read when no data is present"

I have data in the database but still it is showing like this. Help me.

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connec);
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select Title,DateReleased,TheaterName,Name,PhoneNo,Price,userName from vwTicketBooking ", con);
        using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            List<TicketBooking> results = new List<TicketBooking>();
            while (dr.Read())
                 newItem = new TicketBooking();
                newItem.Title = dr["Title"].ToString();
                newItem.DateReleased = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["DateReleased"]);
                newItem.TheaterName = dr["TheaterName"].ToString();
                newItem.Name = dr["Name"].ToString();
                newItem.PhoneNo = dr["PhoneNo"].ToString();
                newItem.Price = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Price"]);
                newItem.userName = dr["userName"].ToString();
                results.Add(newItem);
                return View(results);      
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure your reader has data? Did you debug your code and see it?

Comment: yeah after debug , it is showing the error at this line newItem.Title = dr["Title"].ToString();

Comment: If you are going to return in the first iteration of `while` then there is no reason for `while`. Just do `dr.Read()`.

Comment: Of course you're getting an exception. `newItem = new TicketBooking();` is the only thing being executed **inside** the `while` loop. `dr["Title"]"` is being called outside of the loop once there is no data left and `dr.Read()` returns false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to use  `{}` with your `while` statement because your code works like;

```
while (dr.Read())
{
    newItem = new TicketBooking();
}
    newItem.Title = dr["Title"].ToString();
    newItem.DateReleased = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["DateReleased"]);
    newItem.TheaterName = dr["TheaterName"].ToString();
    ...
```

and after last iteration, your reader will be after the last line, and there is no data to read it. Use it like;

```
while (dr.Read())
{
    newItem = new TicketBooking();
    newItem.Title = dr["Title"].ToString();
    newItem.DateReleased = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["DateReleased"]);
    newItem.TheaterName = dr["TheaterName"].ToString();
    ...
    ...
}
```

Also use `using` statement with `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` as well to dispose them automatically.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the enclosing brackets for your while loop. Your code in effect is only looping the single line `newItem = new TicketBooking();` and when the reader finishes reading, you are attempting to use it again by saying `newItem.Title = dr["Title"].ToString();` which is giving you the exception as there is nothing to read any further.

```
while (dr.Read())
{
     newItem = new TicketBooking();
     newItem.Title = dr["Title"].ToString();
     newItem.DateReleased = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["DateReleased"]);
     newItem.TheaterName = dr["TheaterName"].ToString();
     newItem.Name = dr["Name"].ToString();
     newItem.PhoneNo = dr["PhoneNo"].ToString();
     newItem.Price = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Price"]);
     newItem.userName = dr["userName"].ToString();
     results.Add(newItem);
}
return View(results);
```